# Laptop Motherboard to ALL IN ONE PC

Tags: motherboard, computer-building

I have a completely new motherboard from a Dell Laptop Inspiron 15 5000 Series (photo included).
This motherboard have already connected all the USB,LAN,HDMI ports, and I think but I'm not sure also the CPU and Graphic Card.

Is it possible to connect it with a monitor and transform it into a new ALL-IN-ONE PC like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jeLCQ62vFk)  and if yes what spare parts I need to order?

Thanks in advance!

Please check the photo: 
[image: Motherboard]

Answer (score 0):

Fan, power supply, custom case of some kind, adapter from video output to the video in ports of the monitor, keyboard, mouse, and drives.

Why not buy a dead laptop of the same model from eBay and use that for all of the above?